# Nginx equivalent to lighttpd "evhost.path-pattern"

Tags: nginx, debian, lighttpd, regex

I'm setting up a new server for my personal stuff. On the old box I've used lighttpd for almost two years now. I've read a bit about it and most people tend to switch to nginx since it's development is much more active.

Now i'm a bit overwhelmed by the might of nginx. The coolest thing I've used with lighty was the "evhost.path-pattern" feature where I can simply delegate all domains and subdomains using a more or less complex regular expression and defining "evhost.path-pattern = "/var/www/pages/%0/subdomains/%3/" so I simply have to create a new folder in "subdomains" and the same second I have a working webdir to upload stuff for the new subdomain (or new domain).

Nginx has this construct:

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;

    location / {
        root   /sites/$domain;
    }
}
```

But now I have problems finding a proper RegEx to cover domains and subdomains at the same time (in lighty I've done this by having a RegEx to have catch the domain and negate it for subdomains). I want the main domain (with and without 'www') to go to /var/www/pages//htdocs/ and all subdomains need to go to /var/www/pages//subdomains//.

Any help on this?

Comment: OK, i've figured it out. I have now two server{}. One for main domains (with and without www) and one for subdomains, each with a suitable RegEx to get domain and subdomain name.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>convert from [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/368858/nginx-equivalent-to-lighttpd-evhost-path-pattern#comment376062_368858) to CW</sub>

I have now two `server{}` directive.

One for main domains (with and without www) and one for subdomains, each with a suitable regex to get domain and subdomain name.